# Textbook recommendation for how rain works for a mechanical engineer?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, designforrain

I am looking to find a textbook or even a paper that describes to me how rainfall works. What is the droplet size distribution, how dense are droplets packed, what incident angles do they hit the floor at, what terminal speed to they travel at, so on so fort. Whenever I search literature it is either some detailed physics on thermodynamics of droplet formation in clouds or whenever I search Design for Environment, it comes up with the sustainability stuff and not the context I mean or if I search climatic design it gives me climatic comfort and HVAC stuff. Is there any textbook anyone could recommend on "Design for Weather for a Mechanical Engineer"?

For context, I work in the transportation sector in design as a mechanical engineer.

Comment: Gravity helps, that's why rain falls...

Comment: You will (hopefully) someday learn a lot about engines and steam.  Apply it to the atmosphere.  If you are simply designing stuff to withstand rainfall, just expect a big reservoir of eater to dump on your product- your objective is to give the water somewhere to go.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a resource hunting question. https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "Design for Weather for a Mechanical Engineer" seems different than "understanding how rain works".

Comment: have you not experienced rain? ... incident angle can be anywhere from vertical to almost horizontal ... density is also variable

Comment: Why is a resource hunting question not allowed? I am just asking for a recommendation of allowed literature?